# Problems with const char variable

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a server program in C++ and I am at a method that accepts a `const char`.  I have this code but it won't compile saying

```
27 26 C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] expected primary-expression before ',' token
```

Could someone please explain what is happening to me.

```
std::string str = "Hello";
const char * c = str.c_str();
iResult = getaddrinfo(c*, 23, &hints, &result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `*` in `getaddrinfo(c*, ...`, which you should remove, and the second argument should be the port number as a string:

```
getaddrinfo(c, "23", &hints, &result);
```

Comment: i tried that but then my compiler whined and said 27 46 C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\main.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: oh thanks ill accept it when i can didnt know port number was a string